# How can I take the permission for "users_photo" from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facbook api to access the photos from facebook and to do this we need permission but not able to take the permission. I tried lot but every time permission got denied.

script for connect with Facebook and take the profile picture of user who logged in is:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-facebook.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', ['facebook'])

        .config(function(FacebookProvider) {
          FacebookProvider.init('386514074820288');
        })

        .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, Facebook) {
            $scope.login = function () {
                Facebook.login(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  if (response.status == 'connected') {
                    $scope.status = 'Connected with Facebook';
                  } else {
                    $scope.status = 'Failed to connect with facebook';
                  }
                });
                //getting the user information who connect with facebook
                Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //getting the url for the profile picture from facebook
                    Facebook.api('/'+response.id+'/picture',function(respone) {
                        $scope.imgSrc = respone.data.url;
                    });
                });
            };
        });
    </script>
```

But when I access the album/photos,  I got the **empty** array.....

```
Facebook.api('/me/photos', function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        //getting the url for the profile picture from facebook
                        Facebook.api('/'+response.id+'/picture',function(respone) {
                            $scope.imgSrc = respone.data.url;
                        });
                    });
```

when I search on internet,  I found that to access the **photos**, need the permission from facebook. But when I submitted the request to take the permission every time it denied and unapproved.

Please tell me how can I take the permission?

Answer (score 0):

I think where you're going wrong is that you haven't supplied a scope object to your FB.login() function. The permission you need to be passing into the scope object is 'user_photos'.

```
var permissions = ['user_photos'];
Facebook.login(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        $scope.status = 'Connected with Facebook';
    } else {
        $scope.status = 'Failed to connect with facebook';
    }
}, {scope: permissions.join(', '), return_scopes: true });
```

[As per the Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1)
By setting the return_scopes option to true in the option object when calling FB.login, you will receive a list of the granted permissions in the grantedScopes field on the authResponse object.

Comment: So by doing this, no need to send the permission request from facebook developer website to get the permission for user_photo.Can I directly use it like this......                                                I am new to facebook api, I don't know how can I use it.

Comment: From what I've read on Extended profile properties https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-extended-profile it appears that you'll still need to submit this permission for facebook to review